# Can't debug my iOS project since updating to cocoa pods to use_frameworks! for Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, build, cocoapods, lldb

After cocoapods 0.38.0 I updated my project to `use_frameworks!` so that I can make use of Swift modules.

Now whenever I try and debug via lldb I get the following error:

```
error: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module 'my-app-name' from AST context:
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "/Path/To/Project/Pods/Target Support Files/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit-umbrella.h"
        ^
/Path/To/Project/Pods/Target Support Files/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit-umbrella.h:6:9: note: in file included from /Path/To/Project/Pods/Target Support Files/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit-umbrella.h:6:
#import "FBSDKAppLinkResolver.h"
        ^
/Path/To/Project/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppLinkResolver.h:26:10: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module 'FBSDKCoreKit.FBSDKAppLinkResolver'
# import <Bolts/BFAppLinkResolving.h>
         ^
could not build Objective-C module 'FBSDKCoreKit'<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "/Path/To/Project/Pods/Target Support Files/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit-umbrella.h"
        ^
/Path/To/Project/Pods/Target Support Files/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit-umbrella.h:3:9: note: in file included from /Path/To/Project/Pods/Target Support Files/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit-umbrella.h:3:
#import "FBSDKLoginButton.h"
        ^
A fatal parse error has occurred.  LLDB may become unstable; please restart your debug session as soon as possible.
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of digging and found that if you set `Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules` to yes for the `FBSDKCoreKit` target in the `Pods` project, that fixes the LLDB errors.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I have posted a question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32235105/lldb-issue-with-fbsdk-whenever-i-put-a-breakpoint-i-get-an-error-and-im-unable

Comment: I'm still having the same issue even if I set `Allow Non-modular Includes in Framework Modules` to yes