# LLDB Issue with FBSDK, whenever I put a breakpoint I get an error and I'm unable to print any variable

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, lldb

Whenever I put a breakpoint and try to access any variable I get this error.

If I try to print a variable in the console, I get this error:

```
(lldb) p someVar
error: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module 'Jogabo' from AST context:
/Users/pg/Jogabo/app-v2/ios-   app/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginButton.h:21:9:    note: while building module 'FBSDKCoreKit' imported from  /Users/pg/Jogabo/app-v2/ios-   app/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginButton.h:21:
#import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKButton.h>
   ^
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "/Users/pg/Jogabo/app-v2/ios-app/Pods/Target Support   Files/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit-umbrella.h"
   ^
/Users/pg/Jogabo/app-v2/ios-app/Pods/Target Support  Files/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit-umbrella.h:6:9: note: in file included from   /Users/pg/Jogabo/app-v2/ios-app/Pods/Target Support  Files/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit-umbrella.h:6:
#import "FBSDKAppLinkResolver.h"
   ^
/Users/pg/Jogabo/app-v2/ios- app/Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKAppLinkResolver.h:26:1    0: error: include of non-modular header inside framework module  'FBSDKCoreKit.FBSDKAppLinkResolver'
# import <Bolts/BFAppLinkResolving.h>
    ^
<module-includes>:1:9: note: in file included from <module-includes>:1:
#import "/Users/pg/Jogabo/app-v2/ios-app/Pods/Target Support   Files/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit-umbrella.h"
   ^
/Users/pg/Jogabo/app-v2/ios-app/Pods/Target Support  Files/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit-umbrella.h:3:9: note: in file included  from /Users/pg/Jogabo/app-v2/ios-app/Pods/Target Support  Files/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit-umbrella.h:3:
#import "FBSDKLoginButton.h"
   ^
/Users/pg/Jogabo/app-v2/ios- app/Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginButton.h:21:9:     error: could not build module 'FBSDKCoreKit'
 #import <FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKButton.h>
   ^
could not build Objective-C module 'FBSDKLoginKit'A fatal parse error  has occurred.  LLDB may become unstable; please restart your debug session  as soon as possible.
```

Comment: As a temporary work around, try removing the '#if __has_include(<Bolts/BFAppLinkResolving.h>)' block in FBSDKAppLinkResolver.h (i.e. force it to weak link Bolts.framework)